# Unable to get PCI Ethernet connected on Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: networking, server

First off, it might be useful to explain that my local network setup is:

```
[Internet] <---> [192.168.1.1] <---> [10.10.10.1] <---> [Computer]
```

so, the router at 10.10.10.1 is the computer's gateway and router 192.168.1.1 handles DNS requests.

~~~~~

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 server on the computer in question, but I can't seem to get the ethernet connection working properly. Here's the info that I would think would be useful:

```
user@SAMserver1:~$ lspci | grep Eth
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Coporation DECchip 21140 [FasterNet] (rev 22)
```

~~~~~

```
user@SAMserver1:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:00:65:19:1f:e3
         inet addr:10.10.10.2 Bcast:10.10.10.15 Mask:255.255.255.240
         UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:0 ettors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:0 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:3
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

~~~~~

```
user@SAMserver1:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.10.10.2
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        gateway 10.10.10.1
        dns-search 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

~~~~~

```
user@SAMserver1:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway        Genmask         Flags Metric  Ref   Use  Iface
default         10.10.10.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100     0       0  eth0
10.10.10.0      *              255.255.255.240 U     0       0       0  eth0
```

~~~~~

```
user@SAMserver1:~$ ping -c 1 10.10.10.1
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
from 10.10.10.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.10.10.1 ping statistics ---
1 packet transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

~~~~~

```
user@SAMserver1:~$ ping -c 1 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

~~~~~

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if there's any useful info that I left out.

PS: I did make sure that address 10.10.10.2 was reserved on the router for the server's MAC address

PPS: Trimmed output of "`lspci -vvv`"

```
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21140 [FasterNet] (rev 22)
    Subsystem: Cogent Data Technologies, Inc. Device 2500
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 66 (5000ns min, 10000ns max), Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 3
    Region 0: I/O ports at 1000 [size=128]
    Region 1: Memory at 44000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 18000000 [disabled] [size=256K]
    Kernel driver in use: tulip
    Kernel modules: tulip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so much of "solution," but since I originally installed Ubuntu without the PCI ethernet card, I gave reinstallation with the card in place a try and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: IMO, this is mostly related to the driver. but glad it's working now. personally I rarely do a reinstallation with Linux unless I did 'rm -rf /' :)

Answer (score 0):

You need setup the LAN network first before reaching to the DNS Server in another network.

You got errors from ifconfig, there could be a number of things: hardware: faulty cable, malfunction connector. s/w setting: mismatch duplex, wrong kernel driver for your NIC etc.

When you rule out those things, try have a consistent netmask settings too, just a good practice. as I see three different netmask from your output: **255.255.255.240** from 'ifconfig', **255.255.255.252** in /etc/network/interfaces, **255.255.255.242** from 'route'.

Comment: Whoops, the mis-mashed subnets were a typo (I had to type all that info manually). It's fixed now.

Comment: If by "setup the LAN" you mean configure the routers: they're properly configured. I'm able to connect to the internet through my LAN with other computers and I know that the issue isn't there.  

I know that the Ethernet cable itself works fine, but I can't say for sure that the card or some other components are working flawlessly, but I tried two different NICs and had the same problems. I'm pretty sure that it's a software configuration issue.

Comment: :) you can do a copy & paste. type all takes quite long. do you have more logs (e.g. syslog)? regarding the driver being used by NIC, use 'lspci -vvv' to check. if your NIC is quite new, you probably need to use the latest kernel like 3.8.0 or 3.11.0.

Comment: I appended the output of `lspci -vvv` to the original post (and I found that the 'script' command is truly one's friend when limited to the terminal).  

BTW, the NIC cards are the better portion of a decade old, so I should think the drivers would be included.

Comment: The version of Ubuntu I'm using doesn't seem to come with syslog preinstalled.

Comment: rsyslog it is. try lookup anything in /var/log/syslog* with 'tulip'. see if anything went wrong there. and try to check if the settings of 'eth0' is fine using tool 'ethtool'.

Comment: I'm gonna put off trying to get it to work for a while. (Work setting up the other nodes of my beowulf cluster, give reinstalling Ubuntu with the NIC _in_ this time - rather than adding it afterwards - and see where that gets me.)  

Thanks for the effort.